# MVC3 Best way to custom permissions

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, permissions

I am developing a website in MVC3 and EF Connect to Mysql. As requested I have my own permissions and roles tables. and now need to control access to the views of the website. I was thinking that this would have to use static classes or something similar to allow or restrict access, but I think it would be malpractice. what would be the best way to validate each of the views or controllers?

Comment: use `[authorize]` attribute on controller / actions you want to restrict and `[allowanonymous]` attribute on controller / actions you want to allow